# How to cache counters to speed up the database inserts?

Tags: javascript, counter

How can I cache counters for views.

I have about 1000 pageviews per second and there are about 10 counters that are updated each time. Now the problem is that it is resulting in about 10000 updates/inserts per second and I was wondering if there was way I could cache the counter and then do the update in bulk to speed up the dataabse.

How to cache counters to speed up the database inserts?

Thanks

Comment: yes, there's a way. you could cache the counter and do the bulk update. generic question, generic answer.. so, what's your question?

Comment: How to cache counters to speed up the database inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I guess you're using an RDBMS like MySQL, well, try something other like Redis or MongoDB. 10000 updates/sec should be fine.
- Write a small application in C/C++ that does the caching and bulk updates. If the server crashes you'll lose the cached data but this is just plain counters so you don't really care about it, right? If you already use PHP/Perl/Python for the pages you can also try to use some built-in storage for the caching which lives beyond a single request's lifetime.

Comment: What is the advantage of mongodb over mysql

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect job for Redis counters, are you open to using it?
Redis counters are capable of about 60- 70 000 hits a second

```
redis> SET mykey "10"
OK
redis> INCR mykey
(integer) 11
redis> GET mykey
"11"
redis>
```

Comment: If your new to "NoSQL" databases, you can see the differences here: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html